# PHP - convert EPS to PNG using Imagick

Tags: php, imagick, image-conversion

I am trying to convert eps to png image using imagick.This is the code i am using.

```
     $path = getcwd().'/uploads/1488/791/586/imprint_option_1A.eps';
        $save_path = getcwd().'/uploads/1488/791/586/imprint_option_2E_c.png';
        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->readimage($path);
        $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
        $image->setResolution(300,300);
        $image->scaleImage(600, 270);
        $image->setImageFormat("png");
        $image->writeImage($save_path);
```

but the transparency is not working i got image with white background ( [Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3cH3.png) ). and when we scale image it loses clarity..

Any idea ?

Here is my eps file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwq4DvGGbHVfT0FYTE94WW5GTnc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [setResolution](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php) should be called before reading the image. Thus

```
 $image = new Imagick();
 $image->setResolution(1200, 1200);
 $image->readImage($path);
```

should do it. As for the transparency, can you try to get the input as sRGB instead of CMYK? If I convert first the input file to pdf with `epstopdf` and then use this converted file in the PHP script, it produces a transparent PNG file.